# How to covert text to four bit binary representation using python

Tags: python, binary

```
st = input("Enter the Message :  ")
b = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in st)
print(b)
```

How to convert this message to its four bit binary representation instead of seven bit representation.

I want to convert each characters in a string to four bit binary values ( eg: 1001 ,0101, 1101 ,1000, 0101 ) like a BCD conversion.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "four bit binary representation". Your code currently displays the [ASCII-Value](http://www.asciitable.com/) in binary representation. With only four digits, you can only cover 15 different values, which seems a little low when trying to represent letters.

Comment: Give a sample input, and the expected output.

Comment: i want to convert each characters in a string to four bit binary values ( eg: 1001 ,0101, 1101 ,1000, 0101 ) like a BCD conversion